# Adjusting start and end dates sql

Tags: t-sql

Given a data set in MS SQL Server 2016

```
StoreID PurchaseID ShopID LocationID Starttime          Endtime
1020    20200102    9856  0010    2020-01-08 09:08:53  2020-01-08 09:11:52
1021    20200102    9856  0020    2020-01-08 09:09:48  2020-01-08 09:11:52
```

Here the StoreID is primary key. I'm looking for a query that will change the value of the first record end time to the value present in the starttime of next second record. To be precise I need to look for records that happened on same day for PurchaseID & shopkeeperID combination where the location id is different for both and then grab the starttime of later record and update the value in the prior row endtime.

Note: Here I gave sample size of just two but in my dataset I have more than 2 with above scenarios.

My result set should like:

```
StoreID PurchaseID  ShopkID LocationID Starttime         Endtime
1020    20200102    9856    0010  2020-01-08 09:08:53  2020-01-08 09:09:48
1021    20200102    9856    0020  2020-01-08 09:09:48  2020-01-08 09:11:52
```

Comment: By the OP's admission they have duplicated the question in [Adjusting start and end dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64037999/adjusting-start-and-end-dates).

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be something close to this, though a sub-select won't perform as well as SET SQL:

```
UPDATE 
    T
SET
    T.purchaseendtime = 
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 
                purchasestarttime 
            FROM 
                TABLE_NAME T2
            WHERE 
                T2.PurchaseStartTime >  T.PurchaseStartTime
                AND T2.PurchaseID = T.PurchaseID
                AND T2.ShopkeeperID = T.ShopkeeperID
                AND T2.LocationID <> T.LocationID
                AND Convert(date, T2.PurchaseStartTime) = Convert(date, T.PurchaseStartTime)
            ORDER BY
                T2.PurchaseStarttime
        )
FROM 
    TABLE_NAME T
```

Comment: This logic returns values.

Comment: This statement does not return values. It uses a sub-select to fetch the value. Have you tried it?