# Adjusting start and end dates

Tags: t-sql

```
Given a data set in MS SQL Server 2016

 StoreID PurchaseID ShopID LocationID Starttime          Endtime
 1020    20200102    9856  0010    2020-01-08 09:08:53  2020-01-08 09:11:52
 1021    20200102    9856  0020    2020-01-08 09:09:48  2020-01-08 09:11:52
 1022    20200102    9856  0030    2020-01-09 09:08:53  2020-01-09 09:12:52 
 1023    20200102    9856  0040    2020-01-10 09:09:48  2020-01-10 09:13:52
```

Here the StoreID is primary key. I'm looking for a query that will change the value of the first record end time to the value present in the starttime of next second record. To be precise I need to look for records that happened on same day for PurchaseID & shopkeeperID combination where the location id is different for both and then grab the starttime of later record and update the value in the prior row endtime.

Note: Here I gave sample size of just two but in my dataset I have more than 2 with above scenarios.

I would like this change to get updated to only records that occurred in that particular day. Logic should not update all the prior records end date which doesnt occur on same day. To be precise I would like this logic to get updated only those instances that are generated on same day with different LocationID.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTab1](
StoreID [int] NOT NULL,
PurchaseID [int] NOT NULL,
ShopID [int] NOT NULL,
LocationID [int] NOT NULL,
starttime [datetime] NOT NULL,
Endtime [datetime] NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [TestTab1]
VALUES (1020,20200102,9856,0010,'2020-01-08 09:08:53','2020-01-08 09:11:52'),
(1021,20200102,9856,0020,'2020-01-08 09:09:48','2020-01-08 09:11:52'),
(1022,20200102,9856,0030,'2020-01-09 09:08:53','2020-01-09 09:11:52'),
(1023,20200102,9856,0040,'2020-01-10 09:09:48','2020-01-10 09:11:52')

Existing Data:
StoreID PurchaseID ShopID LocationID starttime Endtime
1020 20200102 9856 10 2020-01-08 09:08:53.000 2020-01-08 09:11:52.000
1021 20200102 9856 20 2020-01-08 09:09:48.000 2020-01-08 09:11:52.000
1022 20200102 9856 30 2020-01-09 09:08:53.000 2020-01-09 09:12:52.000
1023 20200102 9856 40 2020-01-10 09:09:48.000 2020-01-10 09:13:52.000

Final Result set:

StoreID PurchaseID ShopID LocationID starttime Endtime
1020 20200102 9856 10 2020-01-08 09:08:53.000 2020-01-08 09:09:48.000
1021 20200102 9856 20 2020-01-08 09:09:48.000 2020-01-08 09:11:52.000
1022 20200102 9856 30 2020-01-09 09:08:53.000 2020-01-09 09:12:52.000
1023 20200102 9856 40 2020-01-10 09:09:48.000 2020-01-10 09:13:52.000
```

Comment: How is this a more interesting question than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036093/adjusting-start-and-end-dates-sql) one?

Comment: Same question but wanted to provide more information with sample table structure and sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for, but the last two rows of your expected output have EndTimes that make no sense as they are not in the original data set.  But give this a go and see if it gets you what you need:

```
UPDATE TestTab1
    SET Endtime = T2.NewEndDate
FROM TestTab1 T1
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT *,
        LEAD(Starttime,1,endtime) OVER (PARTITION BY ShopID, PurchaseID ,CAST(StartTime as DATE) ORDER BY StartTime) NewEndDate
        from TestTab1
    ) T2 on T1.StoreID = t2.StoreID
WHERE T2.NewEndDate <> T2.Endtime
```

**EDIT:**

This query takes into account using only different locations.  You can adjust the inner most to use either the MIN or MAX StoreID depending on if you want the earliest or latest record to be updated:

```
UPDATE TestTab1
    SET Endtime = T2.NewEndDate
FROM TestTab1 T1
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT T1.*,
            LEAD(T1.Starttime,1,endtime) OVER (PARTITION BY T1.ShopID, T1.PurchaseID ,CAST(T1.StartTime as DATE) ORDER BY T1.StartTime) NewEndDate
        FROM TestTab1 T1 
        INNER JOIN
            (SELECT MIN(StoreID) StoreID, PurchaseID, ShopID, LocationID, MAX(StartTime) StartTime
                FROM TestTab1
                GROUP BY PurchaseID, ShopID, LocationID
            ) t3  on t3.StoreID = t1.StoreID
    ) T2 on T1.StoreID = t2.StoreID
WHERE T2.NewEndDate <> T2.Endtime
```